# Trouble Installing Multicraft

Tags: minecraft

I have been following these directions to get Multicraft on my ubuntu VPS server by following the Linux directions:
http://www.multicraft.org/site/page?view=install

To continue, I need to initialize the database with:
http://your.address/multicraft/

The problem is, when I substitute "your.address" for the ip address of the VPS server, it just says that it cannot connect.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Does your system satisfy all of the prerequisites on that page? This one in particular is glossed over rather causally but could be very involved and would lead to a problem like you describe if not followed:

- Webserver with PHP 5.2 support